# addEventListener not applied to an element(even though via code it is), but no error is being shown

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, fetch, addeventlistener

I'm having trouble with adding the event listener to an element which I already selected and already have console.log(ed) the element for sure.

Comment Line 12 (the issue, addEventListener is not being applied to the element although I have selected the correct element)...

The comments in the Js explain the flow of the simple program step by step, from the point when the button is being clicked.

```
// HTML --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Fetching requests</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button style="cursor: pointer;">Show Planets</button>
    <table border="5px" id="planetsFilms">
        <thead>
            <th>Planets: </th>
            <th>Film titles: </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table> 


    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



JS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

let tBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
let btnShowPlanets = document.querySelector("button"); 
let tBodyPlanetFilms = planetsFilms.querySelector("tbody");


let links = [];
let tdLinks = [];

function printThing(resultElement, thing){
    resultElement.innerHTML += `<td>${thing}</td>`;
}
function doWork(){ // 2
    fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1") // 3
    .then(response => response.json()) // 4 
    .then(responseObj => { // 5
        for(let i = 0; i < responseObj.results.length; i++){
            printThing(tBodyPlanetFilms, responseObj.results[i].name); // 6 print all names..
            for(let y = 0; y < responseObj.results[i].films.length; y++){
                links.push(responseObj.results[i].films[y]); //     // 7 store all links in array links...
            }
        }


        return new Promise(resolve =>{
            resolve(links); // 8 the array links, has all of the links
        })
    })
    .then(links => {
        for(let link of links){ 
            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerText = link;
            tdLinks.push(td); // 9 store all links, as td ELEMENT in an array tdLinks
        }


        return new Promise(resolve =>{
            resolve(tdLinks); // 10 the array tdLinks, has all of the td ELEMENTS (which inside contain the link)
        })
    })
    .then(tdElements =>{
        console.log(tdElements); 
        for(let el of tdElements){
            printThing(tBodyPlanetFilms, el.innerHTML); // 11 print each one of the link(thats inside the td element)
        }

        console.log(tdElements[0]);
        tdElements[0].addEventListener("click", () =>{ // 12 add event listener to the first td element 
             console.log("Clicked? Nope! :/");
        });

        /*
        for(let element of tdElements){ // 13 add event listener to all of the td elements
            console.log(element);
            element.addEventListener("click", () =>{
                console.log("Clicked? Nope.. :(");
            })
        }
        */
    })
}

btnShowPlanets.addEventListener("click", _ =>{
    doWork(); // 1

    btnShowPlanets.style.display = `none`;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inserting the td elements that you created into the dom. You are using innerHTML to insert a string representation of the elements which results in a new td dom element being created. You should consider using appendChild instead of innerHTML to add your td elements.

Comment: Thanks the problem was in the printThing function and you were right the .innerHTML doesn't work properly when combined with addEventListener... The issue was resolved by creating the elements and appending Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

As was already posted, adding elements to the dom by using `element.innerHTML += '<td>new stuff</td>')` is not a good strategy. That way only the text of an element gets added.

Instead you have to create an element, add the event listener, and then add the new element to some other element in the dom, i.e. using the documents methods `createElement` and `appendChild`.

If you're dealing with a table you can also use `insertRow` and `insertCell`. Check out the snippet below.

```js
let btnShowPlanets = document.querySelector("button"); 
let tBodyPlanetFilms = document.getElementById('planetsFilms')

btnShowPlanets.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=1") // 3
  .then(response => response.json()) // 4 
  .then(responseObj => { // 5
    responseObj.results.forEach((obj, i) => {
      const row = tBodyPlanetFilms.insertRow(i + 1)
      const cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
      cell1.innerHTML = obj.name
      const cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
      cell2.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("clicked on " + obj.name + "'s movies"))
      cell2.innerHTML = obj.films.join(', ')
    })
  })
  btnShowPlanets.style.display = `none`;
});
```

```html
<body>
    <button style="cursor: pointer;">Show Planets</button>
    <table border="5px" id="planetsFilms">
        <thead>
            <th>Planets: </th>
            <th>Film links: </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was in the printThing function and you were right the .innerHTML doesn't work properly when combined with addEventListener...  
 The issue was resolved by creating the elements and appending Thanks a lot!